# Visual Studio 2017 Default Button Icons

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017.
I like using everything out-of-the-box as much as possible, sometimes you just need a button and you quickly need an image, so I was wondering are there some default icons in VS that you can quickly use, without the hassle of searching the internet for stock images?

The reason why I'm asking this is that I always wondered when you add default buttons to ToolStrip some default icons show up, like save icon etc.. So I'm just guessing that VS has this icons somewhere stored.

p.s. I searched the internet but I did not found the answer to this question for my version of VS, and I'm wondering if anything changed. Concretely I'm searching for configuration icon, like a spanner or a cog.

Comment: Older versions of VS had an image library, but I think it was removed a few years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the visual studio image library from here

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825

The is also Syncfusions metro studio
https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the first thing. For second, I'm not interested in third party solutions.